# Parse JSON object from a POST request body in Django/python based server

Tags: python, json, django, xmlhttprequest

I am using the following function to send JSON formatted data to my Django based server which stores the user keys generated for users in a database. When I try to access the `request.body` on the server side using python on Django, it gets printed as a string `[object Object]`. How do I handle this part of parsing the json from the `request.body` on server side.
    function completeKeygen(data)
    {
        var key_data = {
            'user_id':user_id,
            'keys':data
        }
        delete data['action'];
        console.log("Sending UBE Keys to User");
        console.log(key_data);

```
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("POST",CLOUD_SERVER+'add_ube_keys',true);
    oReq.responseType = "json";
    oReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    oReq.onload = function(oEvent){
        console.log(oReq.response.success);
    };
    oReq.send(key_data);
}
```

For reference the server side code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def add_ube_keys(request):
    data = request.POST
    print data.get('user_id')
    return_data = {
        'success':True
    }
    rdata = json.dumps(return_data)
    return HttpResponse(rdata, content_type='application/json')
```

Unlike the possibly duplicate question, I am getting the `Querydict` object on `print request.POST` returns `<QueryDict: {}>`. Why is it empty ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django request Post json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958705/django-request-post-json)

Comment: Finding the answer on SO took me about 1'27''...

Comment: You must be a genius @brunodesthuilliers but I am a noob learner for sure, politeness alongside knowledge doesn't costs much anyways. Thanks :)

Comment: `print request.POST` returns `<QueryDict: {}>`, not the one populated as given in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958705/django-request-post-json

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what is wrong with my approach in the question mentioned above but I solved this in three steps:

1. I added `JSON.stringify(key_data)` in the javascript before sending the XMLHttpRequest.
2. Changed `application/json` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
3. Now the python side treats the data as a normal string, so I used `json.loads(request.body)` to extract the json object from the stringified data.

The above two steps have been taken from the previously posted question:
[How to receive POST data in python when using XMLHttpRequest()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355659/how-to-receive-post-data-in-python-when-using-xmlhttprequest)

Answer (score 0):

`request.POST` only includes form data now. You'll have to parse out the JSON from `request.body`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST